# Showing that $A$ admits a basis of eigenvectors for $\mathbb{R}^n$ given that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How would I show that $A$ admits a basis of eigenvectors for $\mathbb{R}^n$ given that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix?

So $D = P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix, but we do not know that it is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues?

So far I have shown the the determinant of $A$ and $D$ are equal -- but that doesn't really get me anywhere, other than that $A$ has a non-zero determinant $\Rightarrow$ the columns are linearly independent? This means that that the column space is $n-dimensional$ which implies that there are $n$ eigenvectors?

Please correct me if I am mistaken, and advise me further on!

Comment: It seems like you're hazy on the general concept of a proof.  You should begin by assuming that $D = P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix (so, *"we know that it is a diagonal matrix"*), and conclude from there that $A$ admits a basis of eigenvectors for $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: The easiest approach here is to show that the columns of $P$ must be eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sorry I meant to say "but we don't know that is a diagonal matrix **of eigenvalues** "

Comment: How would I show that the columns of $P$ must be (I assume you meant to day) eigenvectors of $A$ ?

Comment: Similar matrices have same Eigen values. The diagonal matrix should have only Eigen values of A as elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the diagonal entries of $D$ will be the eigenvalues, and the columns of $P$ the eigenvectors, and this is what we will prove.

Let $p_1,\dots,p_n$ denote the columns of $P$, and let $d_1,\dots,d_n$ denote the diagonal entries of $D$.  Rewrite $D = P^{-1}AP$ as $PD = AP$.  For the left side, note that
$$
PD = \pmatrix{p_1 & \cdots & p_n} \pmatrix{d_1 \\ & \ddots \\ & & d_n} = 
\pmatrix{d_1 p_1 & \cdots & d_n p_n}
$$
Either show this using block-matrix multiplication, or confirm it by carefully going through the appropriate definition of matrix multiplication.

On the other side, we have
$$
AP = A \pmatrix{p_1 & \cdots & p_n} = \pmatrix{Ap_1 & \cdots & A p_n}
$$
The same note applies to this manipulation.

Since these two matrices are equal, the columns of $P$ must be eigenvectors.  Since we know that $P$ is invertible, they must form a basis of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: A proof along these lines is presented in Gilbert Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*

Comment: And is a diagonal matrix strictly defined by non-zero entries along the diagonal? Eg: Could you have $d_i = 0 \neq d_j$ ?

Comment: You can have zeros on the diagonal.  The only requirement is that the *off-diagonal entries are zero*.

Comment: So if P is invertible, we can say that there are $n$ unique eigenvectors and thus form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ ? 

I'm just worried about the basis requirement

Comment: A matrix is invertible if and only if its columns form a basis of $\Bbb R^n$